# Updating every row with different value in hive

Tags: sql, hive

I have 2 tables

table1

```
key     comment
1       null
2       null
3       null
1       null
1       null
2       null
```

table2

```
key     type
1       1
2       2
3       3
```

I need

table1

```
key     comment
1       1
2       2
3       3
1       1
1       1
2       2
```

I tried this.

```
UPDATE table1 hist
SET comment = (
    Select type
    from table2 mta
    WHERE hist.key = mta.key
    );
```

Didn't work. Subqueries are not supported it seems. The only thing left is to do a left join, but I am curious if it's possible without it.

These are create statements. `SHOW CREATE TABLE`

```
CREATE TABLE `db.evkuz`(
  `subs_key` string,
  `mtr_comments` string)
ROW FORMAT SERDE
  'org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.lazy.LazySimpleSerDe'
STORED AS INPUTFORMAT
  'org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TextInputFormat'
OUTPUTFORMAT
  'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.HiveIgnoreKeyTextOutputFormat'
```

---

```
CREATE VIEW `db.RCR` AS 
Select `a`.`line`[64] as `SUBS_KEY`
, `a`.`line`[63] as `TYPE`
from(
  Select split(`rcr`.`line`, '\\|') as `LINE`
  from `db`.`MAK_RCR`
) `a`
```

these are results of `describe table`

evkuz

```
subs_key                string
mtr_comments            string
```

rcr

```
subs_key                string
type                    string
```

this is the update statement

```
UPDATE t1 
SET t1.MTR_COMMENTS = t2.TYPE
FROM db.evkuz t1
inner join db.RCR t2 
on t1.SUBS_KEY = substr(t2.SUBS_KEY, 2);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
update t1
set t1.comment =t2.type
from 
dbo.Table_1 t1
inner join dbo.Table_2 t2 ON t2.keys = t1.keys
```

Comment: I get `FAILED: ParseException line 2:6 mismatched input '.' expecting = near 't1' in update statement`

Comment: @Eugene Cuz Check data type of both columns

Comment: @Eugene Cuz Send me your both table scripts